# Getting a transparent screen when trying to make something in LWJGL

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I've been trying to get into LWJGL. But the things I try don't seem to work properly. First off, I installed it the way it was described [here](http://lwjgl.org/installation.php) on Eclipse.

It told me to test everything first, so I did that. It gave me the output expected and showed a window. The window was transparent though. I didn't really think it was something wrong. So I just started with the lwjgl basic tutorial, and when I tried [this code](http://lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=LWJGL_Basics_3_%28The_Quad%29) I still got a transparent screen. Even if I just copy the code from the example.

I'm pretty sure my drivers are OK, because I can run Minecraft with around 30~40 fps and Minecraft uses lwjgl too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, to answer my own question here. I started up Eclipse again later this day. And for some really odd reason it worked after that. How dumb it may sounds, restarting worked for me.

Edit: It seems like the problem is that when I don't have much RAM available it just won't work.